# Windows 8 app opening external app through windows IE

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-8, microsoft-metro, named-pipes

I have to open an external application through windows 8 app. I understand that there some limitation on opening external application through windows app.

But it can communicate to IE app.How about if I communicated to windows IE app and it runs a powershell script on desktop to open the application.

Basically I want to run the following command, is there a way I can do this ??

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\6.2\Client>ax32.exe –startupcmd = dri
lldown_26738

Comment: is this for an internal app only?  if this did work - and I think it would also require configuring IE for desktop mode only - it's unlikely it would pass store certification.

Comment: can this be done ? if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

For internal apps (i.e. not distributed via the store), you are [allowed to use the loopback interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx).

So my proposal would be to have a small wrapper executable which opens a port on the loopback interface and then invokes the Win8 app using the [IApplicationActivationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902.aspx). When the app shuts down, the loopback port is closed and the app terminates again (see our [apprunner tool](https://github.com/doo/metro-driver) for a way to do this).

I'm not sure how this is compatible with your requirements and the normal extended application lifecycle of a Win8 app (suspend, resume) but that way you can easily combine the power of a non-sandboxed app which can run external commands with the UI and integration into the W8 ecosystem/contracts.